# Connecting nodes placed in a cloud and a math equation using curved arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arrows, cloud

I am trying to connect a node placed at `here' inside a cloud shape to a node placed at the 'left(' in an equation above the cloud. I have the following code so far.

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline={-3pt}] \node[] (#1) {};}
\usepackage{siunitx}   
\usepackage{amsmath}  

\begin{document}
\[\left(\cfrac{T_3}{T_2}\right) = \left(\cfrac{V_3}{V_2}\right)\tikzmark{a}^{1-\gamma} \implies T_3 = 393\left(\cfrac{1}{0.5}\right)^{-0.4}\;\si{\kelvin} = 298\;\si{\kelvin}.\]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[name=s,shape=cloud, cloud puffs=16,cloud puff arc=110,aspect=6,text width=6cm,inner ysep=0.1em, draw] (cloud) at (0,2) {Note$\colon$if you do an entropy balance you will eventually end up her\tikzmark{b}e};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw (b) to[bend right] (a.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but the best I have gotten so far is

[image]

Any ideas on how to improve it? Also, is there a way I can format the cloud so that it packs more tightly around the text? I basically want this cloud inline with other text in a document.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! There is also the `tikzmark` library. `inner sep=0pt` for a tight fitting cloud. `inner sep=-2.5pt` for one shrunk in the wash.